# What are the advantages/disadvantages of different ways to store structured data in appengine ndb?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

NDB comes with a lot of property types that can be used for storing structured data:

**ndb.StructuredProperty**
I can see that this could be useful to store other model instances, in cases where it's not useful to store the model on it's own in app engine.
but there's also the **LocalStructuredProperty**. The documentation only states that the value is stored a an opaque value, but what advantages does that have?

**JSONProperty and PickledProperty**
Is human-readability of the data the only  advantage of storing data as JSON?

Comment: JSONProperty and PickledProperty. I think you mean disadvantage, beacause de data is serialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docstring of class LocalStructuredProperty:

> Substructure that is serialized to an opaque blob.
>
> This looks like StructuredProperty on the Python side, but is
>   written like a BlobProperty in the datastore.  It is not indexed   and
>   you cannot query for subproperties.  On the other hand, the   on-disk
>   representation is more efficient and can be made even more   efficient
>   by passing compressed=True, which compresses the blob   data using
>   gzip.

Json and pickle does not have predefined structure.

Comment: Note, JsonProperty derives from BlobProperty so the datastore viewer won't actually show the contents. (There are corner cases where the data is not actually UTF-8, that's why.)  Difference between StructuredProperty and LocalStructuredProperty is that for SP, each field is indexed (this costs extra per field per write) and separately viewable in datastore viewer; LSP is not indexed (i.e. cheaper) and doesn't show well in datastore viewer.  Both SP and LSP enforce the structure of a given Model subclass; JSONP and PickledP can store whatever can be serialized using JSON or pickle.